# Stuck during designing a PI Controller

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, matlab, analysis, sensitivity

I'm trying to design a PI Controller on the basis of this paper: "Design of robust PI control systems based on sensitivity analysis and genetic algorithms." by Jau-Woei Perng • Shan-Chang Hsieh1 • Li-Shan Ma2 • Guan-Yan Chen, for reference.

Here is the link to the said paper:
https://coral-harrie-10.tiiny.site/

My issues are:

1. [image: Formula1]

I managed to solve for A and B, both are real numbers, which brings me to my next point.
[image: formula2]

Here, what are A and B with a dot on top? Nowhere in the paper is anything of the sort mentioned but A and A(with dot on top) are different, which I assume from this:
[image: formula3]

2. My second question is what do I do after I input these "*Procedure*" equations from the paper into MATLAB? How do I proceed from there and how do I complete my sensitivity analysis? This is my first time trying to implement a research paper so please bear with me.

Comment: It not otherwise clarified, a dotted variable is the time derivative of the undotted variable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why going through an overly-complex design procedure for a simple PI compensator? The technique they describe around the [Kharitonov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharitonov%27s_theorem) refers to systems whose characteristic equation coefficients are variables and considered within a given interval. Not something very common in the power conversion field.

Comment: @VerbalKint My mentor wants me to follow the procedure exactly as in the paper :(
He's not being as helpful as I'd like him to be, as well. He gave me the control system block diagram and the values for the variables (like W, Wn, Tc, etc). And so far i"m still stuck

Comment: @periblepsis what if, in this case, A and B are real numbers? My mentor advised me to take let A(dot) = 0 and to take B as jB instead and to consider B(dot) as the conjugate..

Comment: @RinR What I wrote is what one assumes when symbols appear without context. I have no context. So this would be how I'd approach trying to follow, lacking it. For example, [here is something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSZsm.png) from *page 2* of my 1971 book, *"Introduction to Orbital Mechanics"* by Geyling and Westerman (which I read through in 1974.) They just jump right in and use dotted variables, without any explanation or much ado about it. In an introductory book, no less. That's because the authors rightly assumed I would know what was meant without being told. It's the usual meaning.

Comment: @RinR That said, it's also the case that your teacher's specific domain knowledge trumps anything I might say. Since I know nothing about what you are being taught, I can't be of further assistance.

Comment: @periblepsis I actually found out that the dotted symbols represent! The formulae for them are mentioned in one of reference papers given...took me quite some time to figure that. I appreciate you taking your time to reply! Thank you so much!